# Angular set form action based on variable in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying to setup a search form where I can inject the form action attribute.

In my form I have

```
<form action="{{action}}">
```

Then in my controller I have

```
$scope.action = "http://www.somesite.com"
```

That gives me an interpolate error because it has untrusted "http:" in the string. How do I get around this. I know I can use ng-bind-html to put html in the dom but I dont know if I can get that to work with an attribute only.

Has anyone else had this issue. I really cant think of a way around it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are using Angular.js 1.2 or above, you have access to the [Strict Contextual Escaping Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#!), `$sce`.

> SCE assists in writing code in way that (a) is secure by default and (b) makes auditing for security vulnerabilities such as XSS, clickjacking, etc. a lot easier.

within $sce, you can pass a variable to `$sce.trustAsUrl(value)` to obtain it's original value.  So you *should* be able to use:

`$scope.action = $sce.trustAsUrl("http://www.somesite.com");`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It didn't fix it in my app but I just tested the same concept here http://jsfiddle.net/7v2mz24v/ and for some reason I don't need to do any of that and it works fine. I can't see why its an issue in my other app.

Comment: hmm so since this code you posted in your question works correctly in a fiddle, it's not an issue with the code, more likely an issue with the version of angular.js you are using, or something else in the program affecting it.  more code is necessary to evaluate the issue.

Comment: Managed to get it work, I don't know why it works in the fiddle and I have to use $sce.trustAsResourceUrl() to pass it to the form action. Thanks for the tip on the $sce stuff.

Answer (score 15):

I agree with hooligan's answer. For some reason, $sce.trustAsURL doesn't seem to work. Instead, $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('') did work for me.

Comment: yep definitely looks to be trustAsResourceUrl in angular 1.4.7