# AngularJS evaluate expression in "action" attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This afternoon I experienced a very strange behavior of AngularJS.

If an expression containing "//" is in "action" attribute of a form, then the angular gives interpolate error.

Please see the code below. If you run the code, the URL can be correctly displayed in all places except in "action" attribute.

```
<form
id="moodleform" target="my_iframe"
method="post" action="{{'http://www.someurl.com'}}" 
style="{{'http://www.someurl.com'}}"
some-attr="{{'http://www.someurl.com'}}">
{{'http://www.someurl.com'}}
  <input name="somefield" value="someValue"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Here is the Plunker that demonstrates this problem, if you inspect the form element, you can see the action attribute is empty and there is error in console saying $interpolate:interr

https://plnkr.co/edit/R2ypg6WWmro1WdrNy6mX?p=preview

Any idea, thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. 
Here is the original stackoverflow post: [Angular set form action based on variable in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543129/angular-set-form-action-based-on-variable-in-scope)

basically, i need to use $sce service in my controller in order to have an url in "action" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ng-action` instead of just `action` attribute